# How to use two != breaks in program in Python?

Tags: python, line, break

The problem statement, all variables and given/known data
I need a program, which would break and show results once a 0 is entered in input name and input grade.
I figured how to do that in name, but how do I add another break? Like grade !="0"?

The program I have so far:

```
students = []
grades = []

while True:
    name = input ("Enter a name: ")
    if  name.isalpha() == True and name != "0":
        while True:
            grade = input("Enter a grade: ")
            if grade.isdigit()== True:
                grade = int(grade)
                if grade >= 1 and grade <= 10:
                    if name in students:
                        index = students.index(name)
                        grades[index].append(grade)
                        break
                    else:
                        students.append(name)
                        grades.append([grade])
                        break
                else:
                    print("Grade is not valid. Try to enter it again!")
    elif name == "0":
        print("A zero is entered!")
        break
    else:
        print ("Grade is not valid. Try to enter it again!")

for i in range(0,len(students)):
    print("NAME: ", students[i])
    print("GRADES: ", grades[i])
    print("AVERAGE: ", round(sum(grades[i])/len(grades[i]),1), "\n")
```

Also is there any way that I can make Python ignore spaces in input function?

Example: I enter a grade that has "________8" in it (_ are spaces) and the program does not want to ignore it, how do I make it ignore the spaces and just accept the number as it is?

Comment: For the last question, use strip as in `grade = input().strip()`. Strip removes surrounding whitespace from a raw input string.

Comment: For the second question you can use `input().strip()`

Comment: @Acu: First `while` loop will break when user enter `0` in `name = input ("Enter a name: ")` statement? and second while loop will break when grade is `grade >= 1 and grade <= 10` ?

Comment: if  `name.isalpha() == True and name != "0":`, then and `elif name == "0":` when entered into the "Enter a name" area, it breaks off the program and prints the results. How can I use this on the grade area?

Comment: Remember to accept an answer if it worked for you See this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work Note that you will get +2 reputation also! :)

Answer (score 2):

**strip() method**

Use `strip()`  method of `string` to strip the white spaces.

Demo:

```
>>> a = "  Go  "
>>> a.strip()
'Go'
>>> a.rstrip()
'  Go'
>>> a.lstrip()
'Go  '
>>>
```

---

Your code will work fine. Produce correct output.

---

Use **dictionary** to save Student records.

**Demo:**

```
import collections
student_record = collections.defaultdict(list)

while True:
    name = raw_input("Enter a name: ").strip()
    if name=="0":
        print "A zero is entered!"
        break

    if not name.isalpha():
        print "Name is no valid. Try again. Enter alpha value only."
        continue

    while True:
        grade = raw_input("Enter a grade: ").strip()
        if grade.isdigit():
            grade = int(grade)
            if 1<=grade <= 10:
                student_record[name].append(grade)
                break
            else:
                print "Grade is not valid. Try again. Enter digit values between 1 and 10."
        else:
            print "Grade is not valid. Try again. Enter digit values."

for i, j in student_record.items():
    print "\nNAME: ", i
    print "GRADES: ", j
    print "AVERAGE: ", round(sum(j)/len(j),1)
```

Output:

```
$ python test1.py
Enter a name: ABC
Enter a grade: 2
Enter a name: XYZ
Enter a grade: 5
Enter a name: ABC
Enter a grade: 6
Enter a name: 0
A zero is entered!

NAME:  XYZ
GRADES:  [5]
AVERAGE:  5.0

NAME:  ABC
GRADES:  [2, 6]
AVERAGE:  4.0
```

---

**Note:**

Use `raw_input()` for Python 2.x

Use `input()` for Python 3.x